# Solving recurrence relation $T(n) = \sqrt{2T\left(\frac n2\right)} + \log_2n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve the recurrence relation:

$\displaystyle T(n) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{2T\left(\frac n2\right)} + \log_2(n) & \mbox{if }\ n>2\\
1 & \mbox{if }\ n\leq2
\end{cases}$

n is set of all real numbers

I am not sure how to remove the sqrt, by some substitution.
i tried multiple methods by replacing with a different function but i was unable to remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure if a closed-form solution even exist. After-all, this function is best expressed in its recurrence form.

Comment: I changed $n>1$ to $n>2$. Hope that is your intention.

Comment: Yes i missed that, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to at least remove the roots of this relation and transform in to some other form where there is no roots?

Comment: Considering that $T(4)=\sqrt{2(\sqrt2+1)}+2$, I don't think such a transformation is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the name of your function and the base $2$ logarithm, this recurrence arises from estimating the running time of an algorithm, in which case we only care about the value of $T(n)$ up to a multiplicative factor as $n\to\infty$. We may apply a variant of the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to resolve such questions.

In this case, it is convenient to change variables by setting $a_k=T(2^k)$ so that $a_{k}=\sqrt{2a_{k-1}}+k$. Clearly $a_k>k$, and a simple induction shows that $a_k<2k$ as well. Therefore $T(n)$ grows logarithmically. (In fact, with more work we can get that $T(n)=(1+o(1))\log_2(n)$.

Comment: Yes i am trying to find the running true, as i was unable to solve with Masters theorem, i thought of solving the recurrence.

Master theorem can be applied of the form
 
$T(n)  = aT(n/b) + f(n)$

here There is  \$sqrt{T(n/2)}$  so i am not sure if i can apply masters theorem, can you please explain ?

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I disagree with your assessment that because it is estimating the running time of an algorithm we only care about asymptotic behavior. Constants matter a lot in the real world. I don't understand the general disconnect from reality in academia and the absolute obsession with asymptotics.

Comment: @orlp, asymptotic behavior can include constants - as you can see from my parenthetical remark at the end of the post. In fact, I would argue that the point of studying asymptotics of a function is rooted in practical reasoning: more practical  in many cases than deriving exact formulas. For instance, an asymptotic that tells you $f(n)=n^2+2+o(1/n)$ becomes *more* accurate the larger $n$ gets. In general one should obtain better and better asymptotics, stopping at the level of accuracy needed. Since this question had very little context, I chose to stop at the first level of accuracy.